# What is the recommended data type for handling Money (just 2-decimal places) in Elixir/Erlang?

Tags: erlang, elixir

What is the recommended data type for handling Money - numeric values with just 2-decimal places in Elixir/Erlang?

Comment: http://hex.pm/packages/decimal?

Comment: I have tried decimal, i run into problems when using Enum.reduce on mixed numeric data

Comment: You could just always ensure that the data you are using is a Decimal struct.

Comment: so my data comes from a database, I use the TDS library to pull data from SQL Server. `Enum.reduce(r.data, 0, &sum.(&1, &2))` I may not know ahead of time if the data would be decimal or not

Comment: @JustinWood i may not know ahead of time

Comment: If you `Decimal.new/1` a `Decimal`, you will still get a `Decimal`.

Comment: @JustinWood I dont follow

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Justin probably means `r.data |> Enum.map(&Decimal.new/1) |> Enum.reduce(Decimal.new(0), &sum.(&1, &2))`. This will work even if `r.data` contains a mix of native number types and `Decimal`s.

Comment: @Dogbert iex(4)> ```Decimal.new(0) + 1
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    :erlang.+(#Decimal<0>, 1)```

Comment: So then convert the 1 into a Decimal and use the Decimal.add and similar functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should always use integers when handling money. Floating point operations can have rounding errors and money-handling code that's off even by 1 cent is often not ok. For example, instead of

```
amount = 99.99
```

Use

```
amount_cents = 9999
```

This is doubly important if you are storing the amount in a database since conversion between Elixir and your database and back may produce undesirable results.

Comment: you are right, but you can just imagine the extra layer i need to add when processing ....

Comment: and handling money( 2-decimal data) is common enough to be first class in any language

Comment: Money is a hugely complex topic, tons of applications never need it (I haven't written a single line of code having to do with money for well over two years), and as such shouldn't really belong in a language's core library. I've worked on a system where we actually needed smaller accuracy than cents, for example - having all these requirements in a standard library would probably make it impossible to use (we used integers for that - it's often the simplest solution and unless currencies, etcetera, play a big role I usually advice that, especially with a bignum library built-in)

Comment: @cdegroot basically you are saying scale all numeric calculations to eliminate decimals, so i  can do just integer math? ... and remember to do the reverese scaling too

Comment: Yup. Wrap it in a module and it's nice and simple and fast. And you don't run into all the rounding crap you get when you work with floats. Of course, YMMV - how extensive is the need for money-related calculations, performance concerns, etcetera, etcetera. But it's where I'd usually start probably unless I'm writing accounting-related software (then I want a proper library, one of the ones that other people here pointed out).

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu It doesn't mean you'll be doing integer math; not all monetary calculations return whole numbers, e,g., percentages. That's why there are libraries that allow you to set scales, rounding modes, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton understood, but in my case, and probably most cases, currency/money calculations are rounded to the nearest cent, hence 2-decimal places in my case

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Right, and when you need to round something, you're rounding from something that isn't an integer. Otherwise you don't need to round.

Comment: @DaveNewton I feel **rounded** was the wrong word to use in my previous comment. Currency is really only **meaningful** in terms of it's smallest available unit... cents for example - we cant have fractional cents

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I think you've never worked in the financial industry. Proper rounding and scaling can equal millions of dollars.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using the Decimal library. There has been a lot of thought and work put into handling all the difficult edge cases.

Money, like cryptography, is not something you should implement yourself. You will get it wrong.

Comment: Decimal library is cool. but really think of it, if the currency in question is indeed only accurate/available to the nearest cent... the the benefit from straight integer mth in cents begins to make lots of sense.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Decimal library is the way to go in currency handling logic, 
especially when you have to perform arithmetic operations with the quantities.